# How to show value of selected dynamically created radiobutton in a div using jquery

Tags: php, jquery, html

please help me to display the value of selected dynamically created radiobutton into a div

heres my code...Please tell me whats gone wrong in my code... Thanks

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var div = $("#show_ans");
    $("input[type='radio']").click(function() {
        var radioVal = $(this).value;
        div.html("radioVal");
    });
</script>
```

And the html code is

```
$i=0
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `question_bank` where `test_name`='$tname' 
AND`posted_by`='$fac'");
if (mysql_num_rows($sql) > 0) 
 while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
  {
   if($i<=$maxq){
       ....
       ....
        <table>
     <tr><td colspan=3><?php echo $row2['question'];?></td>
         <td><ul class="menu">
             <li><div id="show_ans" style="display:none"></div>
</li></ul>
         </td>
     </tr>
     <tr><td style="width:250px" align=left>
            <input id="r1" type="radio" name="<?php echo "s_option".$i;?>" value="<?php echo $row2['choice_a'];?>" ><?php echo $row2['choice_a'];?>
         </td>
         <td style="width:250px" align=left>
            <input id="r1" type="radio" name="<?php echo "s_option".$i;?>" value="<?php echo $row2['choice_b'];?>" ><?php echo $row2['choice_b'];?>
         </td>
         <td style="width:250px" align=left>
            <input id="r1" type="radio" name="<?php echo "s_option".$i;?>" value="<?php echo $row2['choice_c'];?>" ><?php echo $row2['choice_c'];?>
         </td>
         <td style="width:250px" align=left>
            <input id="r1" type="radio" name="<?php echo "s_option".$i;?>" value="<?php echo $row2['choice_d'];?>" ><?php echo $row2['choice_d'];?>
         </td>
     </tr>
    </table>
....
....
```

If any clicks on the radio button it should produce the value on corresponding div and it shall be repeated for all the loop repeats. 
please guide me thanks in advance.

Comment: you are missing `$(document).ready();` and its `html()` not `Html()`

Comment: @Dipesh Now its edited... but still....

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Corrections

**Replace**

```
<li><div id="show_ans" style="display:none"></div>
```

**To**

```
<li><div class="show_ans" style="display:none"></div>
```

**AND**

**Replace**

```
var div = $("#show_ans"); 
$("input[type='radio']").click(function() {
var radioVal = $(this).value;
div.Html("radioVal");
```

**TO**

```
var div = $(".show_ans"); 
$("input[type='radio']").click(function() {
var radioVal = $(this).value;
div.html(radioVal);
```

above changes because you are repeating your self in `while` loop with **more than one dom having same id and that's not allowed.** So convert `DIV` `id` to `class` and also see `jQuery` code update.

Also make sure you add `.show()` to remove `div display:none;` inline `css` so it can be visible to user when `click` event fire.

**Example**

`div.show();`

**Comment Answer**

```
$("input[type='radio']").click(function()
{
    var div = $(this).closest('table').find(".show_ans");
    var radioVal = $(this).val();
    div.html(radioVal).show();
});
```

what i did is selected nearest `parent` `table` and inside of that we `find` particular `DOM show_ans div class` and then `replace html` and then show it.

Comment: its showing the selected value in all the divs formed in loop but... i need it to show the distinct selected value in every loop in each div

Comment: so put `var div = $("#show_ans");` inside click event code and use it as described in answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace

```
div.Html("radioVal");
```

with

```
div.html(radioVal);
```

and also if you can change the event as change like (but its optional and suggestable only)

```
$("input[type='radio']").click(function() {
```

And put your script in document.ready like

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){        
        var my_div = $("#show_ans");         //change div to my_div
        $("input[type='radio']").change(function() {
           var radioVal = $(this).val();     //This is not value it is val();
           my_div.html(radioVal);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for fast Reply Gautham. but it dint work...

Comment: @Kalyan is it working now..??

Comment: See my edit once it is not value it is val()

Comment: Pls look at the div. its in list tag... any changes needed accordingly or is it ok?

Comment: First change value to val() and check

Comment: still its n't working....

Comment: Nope.....Now the script will work fine....you need to check the php code and alert the radioVal and tell me

Comment: And where is your show_ans div..??

Comment: change div variable to my_div

Comment: @kalyan still not working..??then check the values form the db that you are assigning for the checkbox values

Comment: @gautham db data is perfectly assigned... and also i used div.show() and its working partially

Answer (score 0):

Your correct code is:

**// html code**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td colspan=3>demo</td>
        <td>
            <ul class="menu">
                <li>
                    <div id="show_ans" style="display:none"></div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="width:250px" align=left>
            <input id="r1" type="radio" name="k" value="5" />5</td>
        <td style="width:250px" align=left>
            <input id="r1" type="radio" name="k" value="6" />6</td>
        <td style="width:250px" align=left>
            <input id="r1" type="radio" name="k" value="7" />7</td>
        <td style="width:250px" align=left>
            <input id="r1" type="radio" name="k" value="8" />8</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**// java script code**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var div = $("#show_ans");
    $("input[type='radio']").click(function () {
        var radioVal = $(this).val();
        div.html(radioVal);
    });
});
```

**Note:**

You are using `'<div id="show_ans" style="display:none"></div>'` then tell me how can you see div if it's already display none. if you will check with `Firebug` you can see you radio value in "show_ans" div. Good luck!! :)